# How to choose license for project with libraries

Tags: licensing

I'm developing an open source project, and I use several open source libraries. These libraries are licensed under one the following licenses,

- MIT
- Apache License 2.0
- BSD
- GPLv3

Do I have any limitations on what licenses I can use for my own code? If so, which licenses are available to me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawyers don't tend to respond much on stackoverflow, and that's who you should ask.

My non-lawyer opinion is that since you're using a GPLv3 library, your options are going to be limited, but I don't know if the limitation will be that you must also be GPLv3, or if that licence permits you to use some other compatible license. The other licenses you're using are much more flexible for you as the developer.

Answer (score 2):

[IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), but seeing that the GPL is a sticky license (unlike the other ones), you need to check along their understanding of whats compatible and whats not. For example see their [compatible licenses](http://gplv3.fsf.org/wiki/index.php/Compatible_licenses) page.